# Mule : Placing DB select output as JSON array in Json Object

Tags: mule

I need to construct a json object like below

{ "Name":"Tom", "Hobbies":["Fishing","Reading"],"Cars": [{"Make":"Honda","Model":"Civic","Price":"25000"},{"Make":"Toyota","Model":"Camry","Price":"20000"}]

I am constructing this JSON object in a Java transformer. I am get this value [{"Make":"Honda","Model":"Civic","Price":"25000"},{"Make":"Toyota","Model":"Camry","Price":"20000"}] from DB query. But when I try to add this as JSON array in the transformer, it's throwing string can't be casted as JSON Array. Please let me know how to go about it.

Comment: can you show you dw transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Just use transform message activity with snippet below.

%dw 1.0
 %output application/json

---

{
     Name: "Tom",
     Hobbies: ["Fishing","Reading"],
     Cars :  payload 
     }